# Recording network traffic peak per second every 5 Minutes

Tags: linux, networking, monitoring

I would like to monitor my peak network usages. I already use `munin` to monitor network traffic in a 5 minute sample. But as we have lot of peaks of http traffic which lasts only a few seconds I want to know the **peak network usage per second** in the last 5 minutes not the average.

At the moment I use `iftop` which is an easy to see the peak usage. But `iftop` can only run interactively. I use screen to get it running and can look into it on a regular basis.

How can I use `iftop` or a similar tool to just write out the peak network usage in the last 5 minutes every 5 minutes. I just need a file with lines like this:

```
2014-06-17 15:43:12 TX: 14,3 MBit/s RX: 16,2 MBit/s Sum: 29,6 MBit/s
2014-06-17 15:48:12 TX: 11,3 MBit/s RX: 12,2 MBit/s Sum: 22,3 MBit/s
```

and so on.

I tried `ntop` but it is quite a bit of overhead and I can't get the data easily into munin. And it does not write out peaks per 5 Minutes.

Does anybody know a tool or efficient script for this?

Comment: you *can* [make Munin record data at 1 second intervals](http://munin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugin/supersampling.html), you know?

Comment: Now that you edited the question, it seems not make sense any more. What exactly is it you are missing with supersampling and 1-second intervals? The "Max" line in your graph?

Comment: munin supersampling is great. I will implement it. I already upvoted your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Munin 2.0 you can use a feature called [supersampling](http://munin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugin/supersampling.html) to collect data points with 1-second resolution. The Munin polling interval still will be 5 minutes, the respective Munin plugin is responsible for actively collecting and storing the high-resolution data. There is a sample implementation - [the `multicpu1sec` plugin](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/contrib/tree/master/plugins/system/multicpu1sec) which is recording `mpstat` data.

Now the graphs Munin presents you are a different story. Munin is using [RRDtool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdtool.en.html) for graphing, which in turn is able to use different consolidation functions (CF) to represent more than one data point into a single pixel of a graph. As of current, [Munin is only able to graph average (AVG) data](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.rddtool.munin.general/8152) and there is no configurable support for other consolidation functions (minimum, maximum, total, last).

You might consider patching Munin accordingly - it does not look too hard to do. Alternatively, you might just invoke `rrdtool graph` with custom parameters and a different consolidation function as it suits your needs. Just look into your `munin-cgi-graph.log` to get a starting point for playing around. If you only need it on a case-to-case basis, you also might just zoom into the area of interest (which would need you to have [dynamic graphs](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/MuninConfigurationMasterCGI) enabled in your Munin configuration) and look at the Min/Max values printed in the graphs' legend area.

Comment: I patched my local Munin like this and it works like a charm http://munin-monitoring.org/ticket/1737

Comment: @Janning cool, thanks for sharing. I am sure this will come in handy at some time.

Answer (score 2):

Munin is a good tool, and I quite like it. However I have sometimes found that for specific use cases, doing my own sampling, and using `rrdtool` works better.

In this case - you can probably get the raw data you want by ifconfig, and look at rx and tx bytes.

This you can feed into a custom RRD build around `DERIVE`.

```
rrdtool create netmax.rrd -s 1 DS:tx_bytes:DERIVE:5:0:U DS:rx_bytes:DERIVE:5:0:U RRA:MAX:0.5:1:84600 RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:84600 RRA:MAX:0.5:60:12960 RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:60:12960
```

Grab the values from ifconfig in a simple script, and update it into rrdtool using:

```
rrdtool update netmax.rrd N:12312321:341241
```

(e.g. tx bytes, rx bytes from your ifconfig).

Then graph it:

```
rrdtool graph -e now -s end-6h netmax.png DEF:tx_max=netmax.rrd:tx_bytes:MAX DEF:rx_max=netmax.rrd:rx_bytes:MAX LINE1:tx_max#00FF00:tx_max LINE1:rx_max#0000FF:rx_max
```

Not too hard to build a script around it for ad-hoc usage, and is exactly what Munin uses behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

would sar meet your needs? For example

```
sar -n ALL 5 1
```

will give you stats for 5 seconds 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

Please define "peak".

Since `bandwidth = dataVolume / time`, the term is meaningless without reference to the period over which the peak was observed.

If you want to limit the minimum peak width to 1 second intervals that's fine, but by definition you must therefore sample once every second.  And even if you do that, an intense burst of traffic that only lasts 1/10th of a second would appear 10x smaller than it would have if you had sampled at 0.1 second intervals.

To think of it another way, an analogy for "bandwidth" would be the power of a laser, where `power = energy / time`.  A 1 mW handheld laser pointer is 1 millijoules of (continuous) energy per second and is considered perfectly safe, but if you squeezed that 1 mJ into a single nanosecond you'd have a pulse laser of one *megawatt* power.

Comment: You are right. I meant the peak in Mbit/s. Thank you.

Comment: Average bandwidth is still measured in (M)bps - the resolution needs to be specified separately.